# MySQL ROUND and AVG not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, rounding

hi i am tying to use `mysql` `ROUND` and `AVG` functions ,

```
public function get_average_rating_by_specialty($shop_id,$where_array=array())
    {

        $this->replica->select('PreferenceToLOBID,PreferenceID , AVG(ROUND(AvarageRating)) as AvarageRating');
        $this->replica->from('*******');
        $this->replica->where(array('ShopID'=>$shop_id,'IsDelete'=>0));

        if($where_array)
        {
            $this->replica->where($where_array);
        }

        $this->replica->group_by('PreferenceID,PreferenceToLOBID');     
        $result = $this->replica->get();


        return $result->result_array();
    }
```

here i m trying to get average values after round the `AvarageRating` value,

i have only one record that matches my conditions  in that row the `AvarageRating` value is 4.5

but the query result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [PreferenceToLOBID] => 29
            [PreferenceID] => 654
            [AvarageRating] => 4.0000
        )

)
```

when i remove `ROUND` this works correctly , but i want to round the `AvarageRating` values before get the average

in this case i expect 4.5 to be the result , why it's returning 4

please help , thanks in advance.

Comment: @JeremySmyth ROUND(4.5) will result 5

Comment: I don't believe you, that it's value is 4.5, because: `SELECT AVG(ROUND(4.5));` gives 5 on my system.

Comment: See the mysql docs:

"For approximate-value numbers, the result depends on the C library. On many systems, this means that ROUND() uses the "round to nearest even" rule: A value with any fractional part is rounded to the nearest even integer."

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round

Comment: Are you taking the average of averages? That's often considered to be a bogus procedure in statistics unless you weight the input averages according to the number of observations that went into each average.

Answer (score 1):

`ROUND(AvarageRating,1)`

then You can get desired 4,5

Comment: In this case no ROUND function is required at all. Just select AvarageRating directly.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking it to round 4.5 to 0 decimal places, and then average it.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round

WRT to whether the answer should be 4 or 5, pay special attention to this part of the docs:

"For approximate-value numbers, the result depends on the C library. On many systems, this means that ROUND() uses the "round to nearest even" rule: A value with any fractional part is rounded to the nearest even integer."